# How to well order the set of all functions with domain an ordinal and codomain a set?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

**Source**: *Set Theory* by Kenneth Kunen.

**Theorem I.12.14** ($ZFC^-$) Let $\kappa$ be an infinite ordinal. If $\mathcal{F}$ is a family of sets with $|\mathcal{F}|\leq\kappa$ and $|X|\leq\kappa$ for all $X\in\mathcal{F}$, then $|\bigcup\mathcal{F}|\leq\kappa$.

In the proof, the author goes: **"...well order $\mathbf{\mathcal{S}:={}^{\kappa}(\bigcup\mathcal{F})}$**, and let $g_{\alpha}$ be the least $g\in\mathcal{S}$ with $ran(g)=f(\alpha)$." Here ${}^{\kappa}(\bigcup\mathcal{F})$ denotes the set of all functions $\sigma: \kappa\to\bigcup\mathcal{F}$.

**My Question**: How exactly does one well order the set $\mathcal{S}$? It might be possible if $\bigcup\mathcal{F}$ is well ordered, but that is not necessary true in this case.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just as a quick refresher, $ZFC^-$ means $ZFC$ minus the axiom of regularity, right?

Comment: @Arthor Negative-minus the Axiom of Foundation.

Comment: Doesn't the $C$ in $ZFC^-$ mean you can use the axiom of choice to get a well-ordering of any set you please.

Comment: @RobArthan I think you should make an answer out of your comment, given that it contains the solution.

Comment: @RobArthan I think you are correct...

Comment: @Tzimmo It's okay, it is indeed a dumb question.

Comment: @Tzimmo: I think it might be better if we just left it to Dick to say "oops!" to himself and delete the question.

Comment: @RobArthan No, the question should not be deleted. As simple as it is, there might be others wondering the same thing. And writing the solution down as an answer makes it visible to search engines.

Comment: @Tzimmo: I am not entirely convinced by your thinking. But I will write up an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "$C$" in Kunen's "($ZFC^-$)" means that the theorem is predicated on the axiom of choice. If you are given the axiom of choice, then any set can be well-ordered.